# Fatal error after brew update interrupted

Tags: terminal, homebrew, error

While my system was performing a `$ brew update && brew upgrade` we had a power failure and my iMac shut down while updating packages/dependancies.

After rebooting I tried to run `$ brew update && brew upgrade` again and encountered the following error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/': transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
>
> Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master

`$ brew doctor` strangely returns a clean bill of health.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was running `$ brew update && brew upgrade` together.

It was causing some kind of Git formula conflict.

I ran `$ brew update` and then `$ brew upgrade`, formulae were updated and all is good.

Am now able to run both together again.